# mysqldump max ignore-table usage?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following dump command however many of the `TABLE_additionalname` in the `DB` database are still dumped. Is there a maximum number of tables that can be ignored or is this syntax incorrect in some other way (the dump completes so I suspect it is valid syntax).

```
mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob 
 --max_allowed_packet=10M DB -uroot -pPASSWORD 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname 
 --ignore-table=DB.TABLE_additionalname
```

The dump is 41 GBs so figuring out which tables are included is difficult.

I looked at the manual for the version I'm running as well but there is no limit specified there, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump stores the list of tables to ignore in a dynamically-allocated hash table. It will insert the table name into the hash every type, and there doesn't appear to be any code to restrict the number of ignored tables.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysqldump.cc#L847

```
case (int)OPT_IGNORE_TABLE: {
  if (!strchr(argument, '.')) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Illegal use of option --ignore-table=<database>.<table>\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  ignore_table->insert(argument);
  break;
}
```

In the MySQL source code, the file mysys/hash.c has this comment for the function that initializes the hash table:

> Initialize the hash, by defining and giving valid values for
>     its elements. The failure to allocate memory for the
>     hash->array element will not result in a fatal failure. The
>     dynamic array that is part of the hash will allocate memory
>     as required during insertion.

This means if there is a limit, it's related to your system RAM, not the code. The hash table will grow as needed, up to the size of available RAM.

Comment: So I monitored the RAM and it never maxed out. I run `grep 'TABLE_'` on the generated file and I get back `-- Table structure for table \`TABLE_` and `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` etc. There is no DB name in place could that be causing the issue? A `top` shows me `Mem:  32122936k total, 31857708k used,   265228k free,   117364k buffers`

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do. I answered the question you asked: is there a maximum number of tables you can ignore.

Comment: I'll retract previous comment in that case. The tables are still in the export and the max ram hasn't been exceeded.